# I am glad you are come

Tags: grammar, literature, antiquated

In the *Middlemarch* novel by George Elliot, in the chapter 22 of the book three, Dorothea said to Will Ladislaw, a cousin of Mr.Casaubon,

> I am glad you are come….

This is not a printing error, but I wonder, what form of grammar is “…are come…” ?

Comment: I would note that, in some (mostly archaic) dialects, verb phrases like "are come" might be used instead of, say, "have come".

Comment: Here's a usage chart showing how common forms like *[**we**] [**are come***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+come&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3#) was 2-3 centuries ago. I wouldn't be surprised to learn it was even more common than *we **have** come* back in Shakespeare's day.

Comment: How about that! I *did* learn! (Taught myself, actually :) There are [**28 instances of "are come"**](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php) in the compete works of Shakespeare, but [**only 8 instances of "have come"**.](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php) Props to [George Mason University](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php) for opensourceshakespeare search facility!

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/are-come-or-have-come-correct-use

Answer (score 2):

The *[Dictionary of the KJV Bible](https://av1611.com/kjbp/kjv-dictionary/come.html)* says about ***come***:

> ***Come*** is an *intransitive verb*, but ***the participle 'come' is much used with the substantive verb, in the passive form***.
>
> > The end of all flesh is come. 
> >  I am come, thou art come, he is come, we are come etc.

[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/01/is-come.html#:%7E:text=Q%3A%20How%20does%20the%20phrase,of%20saying%20%E2%80%9Chas%20come.%E2%80%9D) explains in an article that

> as the *Oxford English Dictionary* explains, ***the perfect tenses of*** “**come**” (that is, those requiring an auxiliary verb) ***originally had some form of “be” as the auxiliary***.
> So it was once customary for people to say things like “*He is come*” and “*Why are you come?*” and “*I am come*.” Today we would use forms of “have instead: “He has come” … “Why have you come?” … “I have come.”

This did not only occur with the verb *come*:

> Similarly, forms of “be” were used as auxiliaries with verbs like
> “***rise***” (as in “***he is risen***”), “***fall***” (“***the city is fallen to the
> enemy***”), “***depart***” (“***they are departed for London***”), “***arrive***” (“***the
> Emperor is arrived***”), and a few other verbs expressing motion.

This use of the auxiliary *be* instead of *have* has survived in contemporary English but is reserved to certain registers:

> In modern English, forms of “have” are now used as auxiliaries with
> those verbs, and ***the old “be” usages are found only in poetic,
> biblical, or literary writings***.
>
> But we still use “be” as an auxiliary with some verbs of motion, like
> “go” and “grown.” So today we can say either “***he is gone***” or “he has
> gone,” “***they are grown***” or “they have grown.”

Comment: "The end of all flesh is come" reads "The end of all flesh **came**" in the original.

Comment: Really? Not sure which original you mean, but the [KJV Gen 6:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%206%3A13&version=KJV) has _**is come**_.

Comment: The Hebrew original. It is formal and *biblical*, but KJV consistently adds an even higher tone.